# Сколько переменных(ключ-значение) может вместить в себя SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Сколько переменных(ключ-значение) может вместить в себя SharedPreferences? Есть ли какой-то лимит у SharedPreferences?

Comment: Для чего-то объемного обычно лучше использовать SQL

Comment: @McDaggen Да, мне это известно, но всё равно спасибо за ваш комментарий. Просто было интересно узнать про SharedPreferences

Comment: Могу предположить, что лимиты могут быть ограничены самой средой на размер файла (файловая система, память, пр). Но достигнуть лимита по размеру в нынешнее время едва ли удастся. Раньше забьется оперативная память переменными из преференсов.

Answer (score 1):

Лимита нет , только ты их соеденяй (то есть их значения) ,
Короч.
Ты можешь поместить стандартно одну только , но если через метод "end" соеденишь переменные , тогда сколько хочешь .Я лично работаю с java sketchware , поэтому как написать это кодом , а не блоком - не в курсе